# yii2 pjax при выборе checkbox

Tags: yii2, pjax

Добрый день! Как в yii2 реализовать pjax запрос при выставлении или снятии галочки в checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pjax перезагружает блок без перезагрузки всей страницы
по этому если вы хотите перезагрузить какой-то блок при клике на чекбокс, вам необходимо сделать следующее:

```html
$('.checkbox_class').change(function(){  
   $.pjax.reload({container:idContainer});
})
```

Если вы хотите передать какие-то дополнительные параметры, то передайте их в объект reload({
.....
})